# How to nest `insert ... returning`?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

Postgresql can return auto incremented values with `returning`:

```
insert into table1 (id) values (null) returning id;
```

I tried to insert the returned value into another table:

```
insert into table2 (id) values ((insert into table1 (id) values (null) returning id)) returning id;
```

But this throws an syntax error before `into` in the nested `insert`.

How to use the return value of the inner `insert` as a value for the outer `insert`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can chain [data modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with new_t1 as (
  insert into table1 (id) values (default) 
  returning id
)
insert into table2 (id) 
select id 
from new_t1;
```

Note that `insert into table1 (id) values (null) returning id` would return `null` as you explicitly ask to insert `NULL` into that column.

To make sure that a value is generated, you need to tell Postgres to use the default value for that column, not a `NULL` value.